# Arquillian + ear + wildfly in remote container = NoSuchMethodError

Tags: jboss-arquillian, wildfly-12

I have an ear created with ShrinkWrap. I'm trying to run AQ tests on remote (dockered) wildfly 12 container. WF is deployed properly, necessary ports are opened and available. While trying to run tests I get:

```
16:05:42,922 TRACE [listener] Invoking listener org.jboss.remoting3.remote.RemoteConnection$RemoteWriteListener@56babcc2 on channel org.xnio.conduits.ConduitStreamSinkChannel@34dcf94b
16:05:42,924 ERROR [listener] XNIO001007: A channel event listener threw an exception
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.jboss.remoting3._private.Messages.tracef(Ljava/lang/String;J)V
at org.jboss.remoting3.remote.RemoteConnection$RemoteWriteListener.handleEvent(RemoteConnection.java:275)
at org.jboss.remoting3.remote.RemoteConnection$RemoteWriteListener.handleEvent(RemoteConnection.java:243)
at org.xnio.ChannelListeners.invokeChannelListener(ChannelListeners.java:92)
at org.xnio.conduits.WriteReadyHandler$ChannelListenerHandler.writeReady(WriteReadyHandler.java:65)
at org.xnio.nio.NioSocketConduit.handleReady(NioSocketConduit.java:94)
at org.xnio.nio.WorkerThread.run(WorkerThread.java:571)
```

and have no clue how to deal with it.

I'm using:

```
<dependency>
     <groupId>org.wildfly.arquillian</groupId>
     <artifactId>wildfly-arquillian-container-remote</artifactId>
     <version>2.1.0.Final</version>
     <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
...
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian</groupId>
            <artifactId>arquillian-bom</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.1.Final</version>
            <scope>import</scope>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

Any clues?

Comment: Ok, I finally got i working by downgrading to:
arquillian-bom:1.1.5.Final
and 
org.wildfly:wildfly-arquillian-container-remote:8.1.0.Final
(mind that in last on the groupId is also changed)

Comment: Interesting it should be working better with the newer version :) Please feel free to file an issue http://issues.jboss.org/browse/WFARQ. This should definitely be working.